# Why am I getting the following error: Enzyme Internal Error: configured enzyme adapter did not inherit from the EnzymeAdapter base class

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have set up jest and enzyme and can't get it to run. It complains about the EnzymeAdapter base class.

I have tried

`configure({})` with `import { configure } from 'enzyme'`

`Enzyme.configure({})` with `import Enzyme from 'enzyme'`

`new Adapter()` with `import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';`

`new EnzymeAdapter()` with `import EnzymeAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';`

My setupTests.js:

```js
import Enzyme, { configure } from 'enzyme';
import EnzymeAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new EnzymeAdapter() });
```

The error i get for each test class is the following:

```
Enzyme Internal Error: configured enzyme adapter did not inherit from the EnzymeAdapter base class

      2 | import EnzymeAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
      3 | 
    > 4 | Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new EnzymeAdapter() });
        |        ^

      at validateAdapter (node_modules/enzyme/src/validateAdapter.js:43:11)
      at Object.merge [as configure] (node_modules/enzyme/src/configuration.js:11:5)
      at Object.configure (src/setupTests.js:4:8)
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Since I get it for every test suite the setupTests.js works.

The same error appears if I do the configure in the test.js itself

I've been searching for hours with no luck. Has anybody encountered the issue before or have a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like it could be an issue with multiple enzyme dependencies being installed. Try removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`, ensure that you only have one appearance of `enzyme` in your `package.json`, install and try again

Comment: I've tried, but it still gives me the same error-message. Installed with both yarn and npm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the error!

There was an issue with jest. I had to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`/`yarn.lock`, and remove `jest` from devDependencies in `package.json`. Why? Because react-scripts installed a different version of jest than what was written in `package.json`.

Then I installed all dependencies again with `yarn` in the terminal (`npm` can be buggy when it comes to dependencies and versioning) and did `yarn test` in the project-folder.

**EDIT #1**
Thanks to Mitch Lillie for helping me on the way to find the solution

Comment: Glad you figured it out :) Certainly an unhelpful error message, one which I've seen before

Comment: Yeah. Was stuck with it for more hours than I'm proud of :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
import {configure} from 'Enzyme'
```

I changed it to:

```
import {configure} from 'enzyme'
```

at it worked !